# siblings of Animated layout not animating till after animation done

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation, android-view

I am using an Animator ( http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/Animator.html ) to add and remove views from a ViewGroup.  When I remove them the view animates out ( it's "slide up" motion ) but the other children do not react (slide up to take up the space ) to the animation until it is done.  I am presuming because it I am using not setting the animated View to GONE until after the animation.  Is there a way to get the other views to slide up while the animated view is sliding out?  Here is the relevant code

```
AnimatorListener mCloseListener = new AnimatorListener() {
        @Override public void onAnimationEnd(Animator arg0) {
            viewToAnimate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        @Override public void onAnimationStart(Animator arg0) { }
        @Override public void onAnimationCancel(Animator arg0) { }
        @Override public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator arg0) { }
    };

viewToAnimate.animate().translationYBy(-viewToAnimate.getMeasuredHeight())
            .setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION).setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator()).setListener(
                    mCloseListener);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all You're not using `Animator`, but [ViewPropertyAnimator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator.html), which is slightly different and You're trying to animate view translation. Looking at [translation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTranslationX%28float%29) definition it become clear that it get applied *post-layout*, so I assume that other views / view gorup don't participate and don't care about that property value.

I believe, You need to animate `margin` or some other position of the view to make ViewGroup aware of configuration changes. I think it can be achieved with [Property Animation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html), but needs little bit more coding.

Here's some trivial example. Say button add / remove by sliding up / down should be animated from the following layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/button_height"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button 1"
        android:onClick="buttonClickListener" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/button_height"
        android:layout_below="@id/btn1"
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button 2: Remove button 1"
        android:onClick="buttonClickListener" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/button_height"
        android:layout_below="@id/btn2"
        android:id="@+id/btn3"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button 3: Remove button 2"
        android:onClick="buttonClickListener" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/button_height"
        android:layout_below="@id/btn3"
        android:id="@+id/btn4"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button 4: add removed button"
        android:onClick="buttonClickListener" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Then activity might look like the following:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements Animator.AnimatorListener {

    private static final String TAG = "MyActivity";

    /** Queue to manage removed buttons */
    private LinkedBlockingDeque<Integer> mRemovedButtonDeque = new LinkedBlockingDeque<Integer>();
    /** Distance view should be moved up and down, from resources */
    private int mMovingDistance = 0;
    /** Animators to be used */
    private ObjectAnimator mMarginAnimator;
    /** Duration of all animations */
    private static final int ANIMATION_DURATION = 1000;
    /** Id of currently adding view */
    private int mAddingId = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Show the layout with the test view
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mMovingDistance = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.button_height);

        mMarginAnimator = new ObjectAnimator().setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION);
        mMarginAnimator.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());

        mMarginAnimator.addListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(final Animator animation) {
        // nothing to do here
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(final Animator animation) {
        if (mAddingId == 0) {
            final Integer removingViewId = mRemovedButtonDeque.peek();

            if (removingViewId != null) {
                findViewById(removingViewId).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationCancel(final Animator animation) {
        // nothing to do here
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(final Animator animation) {
        // nothing to do here
    }

    /**
     * Listener for buttons click
     *
     * @param clickedButton {@link View}
     */
    public void buttonClickListener(final View clickedButton) {
        final int buttonId = clickedButton.getId();
        MarginAnimatorHelper animator = null;

        switch (buttonId) {
            case R.id.btn1:
                // nothing to do here
                break;

            case R.id.btn2:
                animator = new MarginAnimatorHelper((Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1));
                mRemovedButtonDeque.add(R.id.btn1);
                mMarginAnimator.setIntValues(0, -mMovingDistance);
                break;

            case R.id.btn3:
                if (findViewById(R.id.btn1).getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE) {
                    animator = new MarginAnimatorHelper((Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2));
                    mRemovedButtonDeque.add(R.id.btn2);
                    mMarginAnimator.setIntValues(0, -mMovingDistance);
                }
                break;

            case R.id.btn4:
                final Integer removedId = mRemovedButtonDeque.pollLast();

                if (removedId != null) {
                    final Button removedButton = (Button) findViewById(removedId);

                    animator = new MarginAnimatorHelper(removedButton);
                    removedButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mMarginAnimator.setIntValues(-mMovingDistance, 0);
                }
                break;
        }

        if (animator != null) {
            mMarginAnimator.setTarget(animator);
            mMarginAnimator.setPropertyName(MarginAnimatorHelper.PROPERTY_NAME);
            mMarginAnimator.start();
        }
    }

    /**
     * This view will manages view removing
     * and act as {@link ObjectAnimator} target
     */
    private static class MarginAnimatorHelper {
        /** Name of the property to be animated */
        private static final String PROPERTY_NAME = "topMargin";

        /** Button to be animated */
        private final Button mButton;

        /**
         * Default constructor
         *
         * @param button {@link Button} to be animated
         */
        public MarginAnimatorHelper(final Button button) {
            mButton = button;
        }

        /**
         * Setter for property 'topMargin'
         *
         * @param margin new value of the property
         */
        public void setTopMargin(final int margin) {
            final ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams params = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) mButton.getLayoutParams();

            params.topMargin = margin;
            mButton.setLayoutParams(params);
        }
    }
}
```

There's inner class `MarginAnimatorHelper` which does all main work: changes real view layout parameters which affects other layout elements.